How to get multiple output as a parameter from tensor Flow prediction
I have a JSON like this
{
        "question": "bye for now",
        "intent": "greetings",
        "subintent": "bye",
        "answer": "Till next time"
    },
    {
        "question": "i must go",
        "intent": "greetings",
        "subintent": "bye",
        "answer": "see you soon!"
    }

Where I am training question using Fit and concatenating the intent and Subintent for a Output. But I need output in a different paramter for answer as well.
For example
If I search Bye
So right now its giving me intent : "greetings.bye" and score: 0.99
I need answers parameter with this as well
Training Code : https://collabedit.com/by7ct
Prediction Code : https://collabedit.com/7r3c2
While predicting we are saving the output unique values in a array while sending the text for prediction
const req = {
    body : {
    "intentArray": [
  'incident.info',
  'customercontext.info',
  'skillcontext.info',
  'greetings.bye',
  'greetings.hello'
],
    "text": "thats true"
}
}

As you see in the response top5Results I need answer as well related to that question, but right now its giving undefined
Tried the batch and dataset but didnt get the desired result
